# Matplotlib labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

i have this bar but dont know why the x labels dont show the first label.
It always starts with 2021-11-13 insted of 2021-11-14

```
        ylst = []
        xlst = []
        xlst1 = []

        figure = Figure(figsize=(9, 6), dpi=180)

        for xgrp in get_days_week(3):
            xlst.append(media_dia(xgrp).get("totmedia<1h", "ERRO"))
            xlst1.append(tempo_dia(xgrp).get("tot_viag", "ERRO"))
            ylst.append(str(xgrp))

        x = np.arange(len(ylst))  # the label locations
        width = 0.25  # the width of the bars

        figure, ax = plt.subplots()
        rects1 = ax.bar(x - width / 2, xlst, width, label="N veiculos com media viagem < 1h")
        rects2 = ax.bar(x + width / 2, xlst1, width, label="Total Viagens")

        figure.set_figheight(5)
        figure.set_figwidth(8)

        ax.set_title(titulo)
        ax.set_xlabel(xname)
        ax.set_ylabel(yname)
        ax.bar_label(rects1, padding=3)
        ax.bar_label(rects2, padding=3)
        ax.legend()



        print("-> ",ylst) #this prints: ->  ['2021-11-14', '2021-11-13', '2021-11-12', '2021-11-11', '2021-11-10', '2021-11-09', '2021-11-08']

        # ax.set_xticks(x)
        # ax.set_yticklabels(np.arange(200))
        ax.set_xticklabels(ylst)


        figure.tight_layout()
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, graphframe)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=col)
```

[image]

as you can see it starts on 13 not on 14, why is that and how can i fix it?

Comment: Would you show in which line of code you set xlable of x axis?

Comment: ax.set_xlabel(xname) right beneath the titulo. line 12 counting from bellow

Comment: You absolutely need `ax.set_xticks(x)` before calling `ax.set_xticklabels(ylst)`. In the very latest matplotlib version (3.5), you can write `ax.set_xticks(x, ylst)` in one go.

Comment: added ax.set_xticks(x, ylst) and removed ax.set_xticklabels(ylst) but got  Error: set_ticks() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: added   ax.set_xticks(x)
        ax.set_xticklabels(ylst) and it work fine